# Wrong starting place for <ul> bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists, floating

I have a problem with the initial position of an *ul* bullets. The problem is the following:

I have a *ul* on the (right) side of a floating picture (both of which belongs to another *ul*). When I open the html file or just refresh the bullets are overlapping the picture. If however I resize the page manually or even "restore it down" the bullets go in the right position and stay in the right position. Thus the problem seems just an "initialisation" problem.

```
/* float left */
.leftFloat{
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 margin: .5em 1em;
}

/* clear the previous float */
.clearFloat{
clear: both;
}

/* additional space in lists*/
ul.addSpace{
position: relative;
left: 1em;  
padding-right: 1em;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li><p> text text text </p> 
    <img class="leftFloat" width="55%" src="PICTURE.jpg" />
    <p> text text text </p>
    <p> text text text </p> 
    <p> <ul class="addSpace">
        <li> text text text</li>
        <li> text text text</li>
        <li> text text text</li>
        </ul></p>   
    <p> text text text </p> 
</li>
<li class="clearFloat"> text text text </li>
```

**Position of the bullets after refreshing the page**

[image: Position of the bullets after refreshing the page]

**Correct position of the bullets after resizing the page**

[image: Correct position of the bullets after resizing the page]

Thank for any help, Stefano

Comment: Are you wanting everything after the image on the right of it?

Comment: No, only the text before the class="clearFloat" should be on the right. But that is not a problem, it works, my problem is that after a refreshing the bullets are in the wrong position (first pic.).

Comment: Try using `list-style-position: inside` on your `<ul>`. This should reunite the bullets with their items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems with your HTML. First of all it's a very unusual layout, second, nesting ul inside `<p>` is not allowed. `ul` are flow content elements, `p` are not .

So i changed a bit your structure .

For the solution ( to have the `ul.addSpace` ) on the right of the image, you need to:

1. because img has float:left, you use `float:right` on the `ul`
2. img has `width:55%` and `margin:.5em 1em` , so you need to calculate the width of the ul like so `width:calc(45% - 2em);`
3. `ul` has `padding-left` and to include that in it's width, use `box-sizing:border-box`

Doing this, you get the result below

```css
.leftFloat{
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 margin: .5em 1em;
}

/* clear the previous float */
.clearFloat{
clear: both;
}

/* additional space in lists*/
ul.addSpace{
position: relative;
left: 0em;  
padding-right: 1em;   
float:right;
width:calc(45% - 2em);
box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<ul>


<li><p> text text text </p> 
    <img class="leftFloat" width="55%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    <p> text text text </p>
    <p> text text text </p> 
    <ul class="addSpace">
        <li> text text text</li>
        <li> text text text</li>
        <li> text text text</li>
    </ul>
    <p> text text text </p> 
</li>
<li class="clearFloat"> text text text </li>
</ul>
```